# How can I use CiFilter to give a bump effect using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cifilter

How can I do this in swift?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKb7v.png]

I am trying to set this effect particularly to a position on an image.
Please give the simple code to apply this effect.
Thanks in advance.

[Error while adding distortion bump effect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyDWD.png)

Comment: Where do you want to add this bump effect ?

Comment: @TastyCat I detected eyes from a face on a picture. 
I need to animate it using this effect. Can I do that?

Comment: You ant the eyes to be bumped ?

Comment: @TastyCat animate the eyes. Exactly eyes.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do that exactly @TastyCat !
Just to make the eyes bump.

Comment: @TastyCat how can I do that using Swift?

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com/2016/03/creating-bulging-eyes-purikura-effect.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public typealias Filter = CIImage -> CIImage
public typealias CIParameters = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

public func bumpDistortion(center: CGPoint, radius: Float, scale: Float) -> Filter {
    return { image in
        let parameters : CIParameters = [
            kCIInputRadiusKey:radius,
            kCIInputCenterKey:CIVector(CGPoint:center),
            kCIInputScaleKey:scale,
            kCIInputImageKey: image]
        let filter = CIFilter(name:"CIBumpDistortion", withInputParameters:parameters)
        return filter!.outputImage!
    }
}
```

Comment: It says, "Undeclared Type Filter" in the first line. Which we tried to return.

Comment: No, still not working.
I tried it by importing CoreImage also. No luck now also.

Comment: It will not work on my iOS 7 device. Very sad. The code is fine. But now I am unable to test in my device.

Comment: This code will only work on iOS 8.0 devices. Can I use any similar code to use it in iOS 7.1 ?

Comment: Code from here: https://github.com/fcanas/SwiftImage is pretty much the same and provides even more filters.

Comment: Thanks @LoVo ! But, How can I apply to an image ? For example, I have the coordinates of the effect to be placed. I created CGPointMake and positioned it. Now, I need to set up this effect to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you use the code from TastyCat:

```
 if let image = UIImage(named: "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME") {

        let bumpEffect = self.bumpDistortion(YOUR_POINT  , radius:YOUR_RADIUS, scale:YOUR_SCALE)
        guard let yourCIImage =  CIImage(image: image) else {
            //handle error
            return
        }
        let result = bumpEffect(yourCIImage)
        let theImageWithEffect = UIImage(CIImage:result)
    }
```